# Deleting all data and metrices from OpenTSDB

Tags: hbase, opentsdb

I made two metrices in OpenTSDB for test purpose using the command:

```
./build/tsdb mkmetric temperatures
./build/tsdb mkmetric meterreadings
```

I also entered datapoints in these metrices as using Java:

```
put temperatures 1356998400 23.5 room=bedroom floor=1\n
put meterreading 1430568000 32800 accumulationBehaviour=4 commodity=1 dataQualifier=12 defaultQuality=0 flowDirection=1 intervalLength=900 intervalLength=900 kind=12 phase=769 powerOfTenMultiplier=0 timeAttribute=0 uom=72
put meterreading 1430568900 33624 accumulationBehaviour=4 commodity=1 dataQualifier=12 defaultQuality=0 flowDirection=1 intervalLength=900 intervalLength=900 kind=12 phase=769 powerOfTenMultiplier=0 timeAttribute=0 uom=72
put meterreading 1430569800 35192 accumulationBehaviour=4 commodity=1 dataQualifier=12 defaultQuality=0 flowDirection=1 intervalLength=900 intervalLength=900 kind=12 phase=769 powerOfTenMultiplier=0 timeAttribute=0 uom=72
put meterreading 1430570700 37928 accumulationBehaviour=4 commodity=1 dataQualifier=12 defaultQuality=0 flowDirection=1 intervalLength=900 intervalLength=900 kind=12 phase=769 powerOfTenMultiplier=0 timeAttribute=0 uom=72
```

Now I want to delete all the data and metrices, so that OpenTSDB behave as fresh installation.

In the documentation they mention using scan command, I am not sure how to use this command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is well-written in Opentsdb website. Also, they have google group where somebody already has written answer for it.

> **Syntax:**
>
> scan [--delete|--import] START-DATE [END-DATE] query [queries...]
>
> **Examples:**
>
> tsdb scan --delete 1970/01/01-00:00:00 sum temperatures
>
> tsdb scan --delete 1970/01/01-00:00:00 sum meterreadings

```
If you want to specify zookepeer:
tsdb scan --delete --zkquorum localhost 1970/01/01 min temperatures
```

This will delete all the data stored in tsdb table. But I think it doesn't delete the entry from tsdb-uid table. You can most probably rename the metric name to new name.

```
`tsdb uid rename metrics old.name new.name`
```